# AWS X-Ray shows absurdly long invoke time for P2P lambda call

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, .net-core, aws-lambda, aws-xray

So I have a lambda that makes a point-to-point call to another lambda. We have AWS X-Ray set up so we can monitor performance. However, X-Ray show this odd result where even though the invocation itself takes only a second, the "invoke" call from the original takes a minute and a half.

[image: X-Ray Lambda Invocation Duration]

This makes no sense, since we are calling the lambda as an event (ACK and forget) and using an async call on which we do not await. It really causes problems because even though all lambdas successfully complete and do their work (as we can see from Cloudwatch logs and resulting data in our data store), occasionally that secondary lambda call takes so long that X-Ray times out, which bombs the whole rest of the trace.

Other notes:

- We have Active tracing enabled on both lambdas
- We do occasionally have cold start times, but as you can see from the screenshot, there is no "initialization" step here, so both lambdas are warm
- This particular example was a singular action with no other activity in the system, so it's not like there was a bottleneck due to high load

Does anyone have an explanation for this, and hopefully what we can do to fix it?

Our invocation code (simplified):

```
var assetIds = new List<Guid> { Guid.NewGuid() };

var request= new AddBulkAssetHistoryRequest();
request.AssetIds = assetIds.ToList();
request.EventType = AssetHistoryEventTypeConstants.AssetDownloaded;
request.UserId = tokenUserId.Value;

var invokeRequest = new InvokeRequest
{
    FunctionName = "devkarl02-BulkAddAssetHistory",
    InvocationType = InvocationType.Event,
    Payload = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(request)
};

var region = RegionEndpoint.GetBySystemName("us-east-1");
var lambdaClient= new AmazonLambdaClient(region)
_ = lambdaClient.InvokeAsync(invokeRequest);
```

This is also posted over in the AWS Forums (for whatever that is worth): https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=307615

Answer (score 0):

So it turns out the issue was that we weren't using the `await` operator.  For some reason, that made the calls interminably slow.  Making this small change:

```
_ = await lambdaClient.InvokeAsync(invokeRequest);
```

made everything else behave properly, both in logs and in x-ray.  Not sure why, but hey, it solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand, not adding the await, causes the call to execute synchronously while adding the await causes the call to happen async.